# How to create 2D cameras in swing?

Tags: java, 2d, camera, platformer, swing

What is the best way to create a camera for a 2D platformer using swing, and I want to create a camera that moves instead of moving the background. This is because I'm going to have objects rotated by a transformer and need the camera to stay on the object whilst also allowing zooming and rotation.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Swing / Java2D doesn't have a concept of a camera, but what you can do is store the transform of the camera, and apply that first before any other transforms.

Also note that you are almost certainly going to run into unpleasant performance problems if you're not using an OpenGL-based rendering system. (I speak from years of painful experience.) I would heavily recommend using eg libGDX or maybe Slick2D.